# Should mongoDB be run in a cluster?

Tags: cluster, mongo, docker

I'm trying to implement an architecture that's similar to the coreos's production architecture (shown below)

[image]

Should I run the database as a central service or one or more of the workers?

I figured the database needs some kind of replication, which makes me think that putting it in the worker cluster makes more sense, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: have you searched on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?  You might find better information there.

Comment: @MetaFight I didn't even know that existed. Thanks!